# FileNotFoundError from moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm trying to replicate a gif converter from this [tutorial](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/) but it still gives me errors.

I installed all dependencies for `moviepy` and followed all the instructions.

I'm using windows 8.1 64 bit

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = (VideoFileClip("C:\abi\youtubetogif_project\a.mp4")
    .resize(0.5))
clip.write_gif("a.gif")
```

changing path, changing videos still won't work

EDIT: using double backslashes like this `"C:\\abi\\youtubetogif_project\\a.mp4"` still gives me the error

the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\abi\youtubetogif_project\test.py", line 3, in <module>
clip = VideoFileClip("C:\abi\youtubetogif_project\a.mp4")
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.1.8.12-py3.4.egg\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 55, in __init__
self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.1.8.12-py3.4.egg\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 22, in __init__
infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\moviepy-0.2.1.8.12-py3.4.egg\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 209, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
stderr=sp.PIPE)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1104, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Have you installed [**ffmpeg**](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) in your computer? `moviepy` requires `ffmpeg` to work.

Comment: yes I did and also configured the moviepy conf.py to specify ffmpeg bin's path, and I also installed imagemagick too....

Comment: Run with `python.exe -i test.py`, see it crash, then type `import pdb; pdb.pm()`.  You are in the pdb debugger.  Use it to figure out what "the file specified" actually is.

Comment: I used the debugger, the 'clip = (VideoFileClip("C:\abi\youtubetogif_project\a.mp4")' code giving me the filenotfounderror, I typed exactly like the documentation. So maybe the problem is my windows or the library corrupt? I tried installing moviepy with both pip and from the source

Comment: problem solved.... I specified the wrong ffmpeg path. And only the static version is working. thanks guys